# If $p(a \mid b, c) = p(a \mid b) = p(a \mid b, d)$, then is $p(a \mid b, c, d) = p(a \mid b)$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayesian

Both my intuition, and a graphical model of the situation suggest that the following statement might be true:

$$ p(a \mid b, c) = p(a \mid b) = p(a \mid b, d)\quad\Rightarrow\quad p(a \mid b, c, d) = p(a \mid b) $$

Yet, I have struggled to show, algebraically, that this is the case. Is it true? If so, how can one show it algebraically?

Comment: What is $p{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: From the tags, I guess $p(a\vert b)$ is conditional probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true in general.  Here is my example.
[image: diagram]

Then
\begin{align}
P(A\mid B) &= \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)} = \frac{4/10}{6/10} = \frac{2}{3}
\\
P(A\mid BC) &= \frac{P(ABC)}{P(BC)} = \frac{2/10}{3/10} = \frac{2}{3}
\\
P(A\mid BD) &= \frac{P(ABD)}{P(BD)} = \frac{2/10}{3/10} = \frac{2}{3}
\\
P(A\mid BCD) &= \frac{P(ABCD)}{P(BCD)} = \frac{1/10}{1/10} = 1
\end{align}